# Overflow Issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using a text field when I encountered this problem. I have placed a flat button below my text field. Now, what has happened is that when I tap on the text field to write anything, my mobile keyboard appears. Everything seems normal until here. Now after I enter any data in my text field and press on the done button on the mobile keyboard, the mobile keyboard disappears. And I can press on the flat button below the text field. If I do this, everything is performed smoothly.
BUT.........
When I enter any data in my text field, and if I directly tap on the flat button that I placed, without pressing on the done button on the mobile keyboard, then I get to see an overflow message for a second. Though the overflow message is seen just for a second, it is still annoying. I don't know what I should do. Please help me.
I have attached a small video link that shows the problem. In the video recording i have tapped on the done button on the mobile keyboard and tapped on the flat button. Then, the second time, I have again typed something on the text field and without pressing on the done button, I have tapped on the flat button. You will also see the overflow warning.
Please help me friends. Thanks!!

[Here is a recording of the problem that I have been facing. Please have a look at it and help me. Thanks!!](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gO9Zv7fzKMbVjL95ZKL1x2rHgJiBCoje)

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: TextField(
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
    decoration: kTextFieldInputDecoration,
    onChanged: (value) {
      cityName = value;
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Use `SingleChildScrollView` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please reference this doc https://medium.com/@rubensdemelo/flutter-forms-improving-ui-ux-with-singlechildscrollview-7b91aa981475

You can wrap your Container with SingleChildScrollView

example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Forms',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Forms'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextStyle textstyle =
      TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  final InputDecoration decoration = InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlutterLogo(
                  size: 190,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: decoration,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: decoration,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  minWidth: 160,
                  child: Text(
                    'Google',
                    style: textstyle,
                  ),
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  minWidth: 160,
                  child: Text(
                    'Facebook',
                    style: textstyle,
                  ),
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  minWidth: 160,
                  child: Text(
                    'E-mail',
                    style: textstyle,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```